# Dynamically add css background image to bootstrap 4 jumbotron using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically change the background image on a jumbotron depending on my view content but I am unsure of how to do this. My code so far sticks the image inside the jumbotron as a separate element but as I say, I really want this to be the background image so that it'll scale nicer and I can central valign the image.

```
    <div class="jumbotron" style="padding:0px; max-height: 200px; overflow:hidden; border-radius:0;">

        <img src="@Model.Artist.ArtistHeaderImage" alt="@Model.Artist.ArtistAlias" class="img-fluid" />

    </div>
```

This is the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve

```
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url("@Model.Artist.ArtistHeaderImage");
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Ignore the inline styles - I will be moving them to a class once I've finished. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jumbotron is inside a layout and the individual views are inside RenderBody you could do;

1. Add this to your layout

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>
```

2. Add this to your view

```
@section Styles {
   <style>
      .jumbotron {
         background-image: url("@Model.Artist.ArtistHeaderImage");
         background-size: cover;
      }
   </style>
}
```

---

Or if your jumbotron is inside the view, simply add a style tag above that element or on its header.

```
<style>
.jumbotron {
   background-image: url("@Model.Artist.ArtistHeaderImage");
   background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<div class="jumbotron" style="padding:0px; max-height: 200px; overflow:hidden; border-radius:0;"></div>
```

Comment: @BenWilliams Well, I've been using that a lot, haha. You're welcome!